# Creating a DateTimePicker React-Native Android?

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, datetimepicker

I'am trying to create a `DateTimePicker` for react-native android,the ios side has it in one view but for android its separate. Calling it is not a task but i like to include it both in one view like in ios (my concept in below screenshot).

[image]

[image]

Not completely like the above some how customize it reduce both its size, is there an option to place them at specific portions of screen.

I repeat the case is **react-native(react-js)** not **android(java)**

Comment: https://github.com/xgfe/react-native-datepicker

Comment: The above library that Nilesh mentioned has a mode of dateTime, first date picker will show and then time picker will show.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to customize the android picker and reduce their sizes 
you suggested.

Instead I would use this library: [react-native-date-picker](https://github.com/henninghall/react-native-date-picker). With that picker you are able to select time and date in the same picker, even in Android. I had exactly the same problem myself and couldn't find any solution to it, so I ended up creating that picker.

Comment: too bad you cannot use react-native-date-picker in Expo Go... as far as I can tell there is no way to make it available there right?

Comment: Nope, you have to choose between using the built-in date picker in expo or ejecting from expo and use this one.